# Ошибка cannot resolve overloaded

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции

Учусь программировать на c++. Возникла странная ошибка при работе с функциями:

```
cannot resolve overloaded function 'max' based on conversion to type 'double'
```

Сам код:

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void maxi(double max) {
    int i;
    i=0;
    float y[5]={3,-2,0.9,0.5,1};
    max = -999999;
            for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
            {
                if(y[i] > max)
                {
                    max = y[i];
                }

            } 
    }

    int main() {
        cout <<"max value:"<< maxi(max);
    return 0;
    }
```

При очистке параметра max уже в функции main выдается другая ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
cout <<"max value:"<< maxi(max);
                           ^^^
```

вы используете имя `max`, которое вы не определили. С другой стороны, благодаря директиве

```
using namespace std;
```

вы вводите имена из пространства `std` в глобальное пространство имен. Видимо имя  `max`, которое соответствует стандартному адноритму `std::max` в пространтсве имен `std` также было включено в глобальное пространство имен, и компилятор думает, что в предложении, показанном выше вы в качестве аргумента используете функцию `max`.

Объявите переменную `max` в `main`

Обратите внимание, что в функции `maxi` значение аргумента не используется. Оно перезаписывается в функции

```
void maxi(double max) {
int i;
i=0;
float y[5]={3,-2,0.9,0.5,1};
max = -999999;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Так что нет никакого смысла объявлять параметр для функции, если его значение в функции не используется. Вы могли бы объявить локальную переменную в функции, как, например,

```
void maxi() {
int i;
i=0;
float y[5]={3,-2,0.9,0.5,1};
double max = -999999;

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Кроме того в предложении

```
cout <<"max value:"<< maxi(max);
```

вы пытаетесь использовать результат работы функции. Поэтому функция должна иметь возвращаемое значение отличное от `void`. Ее определение могло бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
double maxi() 
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    double y[5]={3,-2,0.9,0.5,1};
    ^^^^^^
    double max = -999999;

    //...
    return max;
}
```

Также нет никакого смысла объявлять переменную `i` вне цикла, так как она используется только в цикле.

Имейте в виду, что в C++ уже имеется стандартный алгоритм `std::max_element`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, который позволяет находить максимальное значение заданной последовательности.